# Making changes to an Object and reflect it when/where returned in AngularJs Services

Tags: jquery, angularjs, rest, service

I am trying to make some changes to my Object in my AngularJS service and return it. But the value doesn't change and the Object as defined in the first place gets returned. I have also tried the same using Promise Object, but it didn't help either.

```
angular.module('demoService', []).
service('myService', function($http) {
    var gaugeData = {
        maxValue: 5000,
        animationSpeed: 100,
        val: 5000
    }; //this gets returned
    console.log(gaugeData);
    this.get = function() {
        $http.get('myurl').then(function(data) {
            gaugeData.val = data.data.Tweets[0].FAVOURITE_COUNT; //this wont reflect in gaugeData outside this function
            //return gaugeData;
            console.log(gaugeData);
        });
    }
    this.list = function() {
        return gaugeData;
    }
})
```

Can I alter the values of `gaugeData` and return it with the changed values to a controller?

Comment: How you are using `this.get`?

Comment: Maybe the `get` operation not finished when you return the data.

Comment: @Satpal I am calling the get in my controller as follows:

return $scope.gaugeHome ={
          gaugeData:
  myService.get() 
}

Comment: @Qing but it does show the data for console.log(gaugeData); in console

Comment: the "then" method of a promise also returns a promise, not the value that you expect. see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: @o4ohel I already tried it but it returns an Object and when i use then() , it does return the value and i can assign the values to my variable but once I am out of that "then" function, the variable doesn't contain the the value i need .The variable just contains the values that it was instantiated with

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you only return promise object from service:

```
service('myService', function($http) {
  this.get = function() {
      return $http.get('myurl');
  }
})
```

and in your controller

```
var gaugeData = {
    maxValue: 5000,
    animationSpeed: 100,
    val: 5000
};
console.log(gaugeData);
myService.get().then(function(data) {
    gaugeData.val = data.data.Tweets[0].FAVOURITE_COUNT;
    console.log(gaugeData);
});
```